# Why can I change a private attribute out of its class?

Tags: java, processing

I code on Processing for a few months now and I'm trying to use java classes. I'm a newbie on java classes and I believe that private attributes of a class cannot be modified outside this class.
However I did change a private attribute of an object in Processing's `setup()` void. I don't understand why I am able to do that.
Can anybody help me ?

A part of the class code:

```
public class Character {
  private String name;
  ...

  public Character(String pName, ...) {
    name = pName;
    ...

  public void dname() {
    println(this.name);
  }
}
```

The `setup()` code:

```
void setup() {
  player = new Character("John Doe", ...);
  player.dname();  //I get "John Doe".
  player.name = "tara"; 
  player.dname();  //I get "tara", without any error.
}
```

Thank you very much !

Comment: **Where** is the setup code located? this is key. Is it in the same file as the Character class?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels No, the setup is in the main file while the Character class is in a file where all classes are defined. How does this affect the public/private mechanism ?

Comment: @hiberfil I have never used processing, but referring to [this documentation](https://processing.org/reference/private.html): "This keyword is used **to disallow other classes** access to the fields and methods within a class" (emphasis mine). That might be loosely worded, but, as written, if your `setup()` method isn't in a class, this implies that `private` is ignored.

Comment: @AndyTurner It could be a good reason indeed, but I have the same result if I try to change the attribute from a method in another class (note that I call this other method from the setup, too).
I also try to declare the classes in the main file/tab, I leads to the same result.

Comment: Do not name a custom type the same as a well-known type in the standard API, particularly not as one in the `java.lang` or `java.util` packages!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is in the Processing editor, then Java classes are [inner classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html) behind the scenes.

This is why you can access private variables in the class from your sketch. This is also why you can access Processing functions from inside your class.

You could try putting the class in its own tab. Make sure the tab ends with `.java`, so it's treated as a "real" Java class.

But Processing tends to hide stuff like access modifiers from you, so you might be best off just not worrying about it too much.